# Render to print : 300DPI render

Tags: rendering

How can I set the DPI of an image made with EEVEE?

I want a 300DPI render for printing

thanks

Comment: Hello :). You probably know how [DPI works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch). Simply take your print dimensions *in inches* and multiply it by 300. Voilà! - there's your render dimensions in pixels.

Comment: Quite interesting :) Do you want to know how many pixel you need for image printed at 300 dpi ... or how to assign a render (image) info about 300dpi resolution to be recognised by printer? In the first case Jachym's link is right in second case it is not possible in blender, it is a part of metadata that is not possible at the moment natively (from what I know).

Comment: read the second post: https://forums.cgsociety.org/t/high-resolution-300dpi-image-from-blender/1419912
is this right ?

Comment: Yes it is :) Just be aware DPI (dot per inch) as named are inches ... so if you want px for cm dimension you have to divide cm value by 2.54 like for A4 paper (21x29.7 cm) the math is for X 21/2.54*300 https://imgur.com/a/cmcmZTY

Comment: to facilitate the calculation in the blender: https://github.com/zebus3d/Render_to_Print .to facilitate the calculation in the blender:

72dpi in photoshop keeps showing
but I believe that the procedure described in the link I gave solves this. right ?

Comment: Yes ... "Render to Print" addon does the same math as in my screens ... 72 to 300 you have to change in some image editor just disable "Resample" and write 300 dpi. This site is meant to be knowledge base ... so would be helpful if you can create an answer in "Output for Print". Some short description with the screen of addon ... to help others. Thanks